# Multiple Preseeds

Tags: installation, maas, preseed

I just installed and successfully did a test MAAS installation using the generic preseed that comes with MAAS. My organization is looking at MAAS to scale our Ubuntu-based infrastructure, and we were a bit confused.

Is MAAS capable or running different preseeds? For example, we have 4 hardware configurations we have standardized on for different environments. The underlying hardware and the basic configuration varies between each type of hardware and we would like to have a preseed for each environment.

Is that possible with MAAS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible to have different preseeds, however you can work around it by using tags.

If you tag your nodes appropriately, you can customise the preseed templates to use that tag to do the different things that you require.